# Grant containers internetaccess in awsvpc network mode

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-vpc, aws-ecs

**The situation is as follows:**

Two containers reside in the same task definition.

A service with this task definition is running on a specific ec2 instance.

I've configured the VPC of this instance to use a NAT gateway.
This has been successful *I think*, because I can now ping to google from the instance itself.

The problem however, is that the docker containers that are running on my instance don't have internet access.

Switching the network mode to bridge would obviously solve this problem, but I need bidirectional REST traffic in between these two containers. Only unidirectional traffic is possible with bridge-mode, as far as I know.

**My question:**

What can I do to gain internet access from within my containers?

Comment: Also want to open Internet access to my containers using awsvpc mode. Have you found out how to do that? If yes, I would be really glad if you told me.

Comment: you should check your security group for awsvpc network configuration